# Hobo, "Company.lost_is(false).apply_scopes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hobo

The application I am about to develop is under migration from Hobo 1 to Hobo 1.0.3.

This is a line of code that does not work any more:

```
hobo_index Company.lost_is(false).apply_scopes(
  :search => [params[:search], :name],
  :order_by => parse_sort_param(:name, :last_call, :lost, :user, :country, :status, :sector), :user_is => user)
```

The problem here is `lost_is` which does not seem to return values acceptable by next routine which is: `apply_scopes`.

So... how can I solve this problem?

1. Maybe make some changes to make `lost_is` produce values acceptable by `apply_scopes`
2. Or maybe I could change `params[:search]` to search only for records with `lost` column set to `false`?

Thank you!

Jacek

Comment: I also tried another approach: `hobo_index Company.not_lost.*` but it gave me the same result ie. `stack level too deep`

Answer (score 1):

Adding the condition to the scopes should work:

```
hobo_index Company.apply_scopes(
  :lost_is => false,
  :search => [params[:search], :name],
  :order_by => parse_sort_param(:name, :last_call, :lost, :user, :country, :status, :sector),
  :user_is => user)
```

Regards,
Ignacio